# Ajax data via ngResource does not reflect after ngView update through ngRoute :(

Tags: angularjs

I tried a lot and could not find proper answer which can solve my problem. Hope someone will help me out.

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'MainService', 'CONSTANTS', '$routeParams', '$location',
            function($scope, MainService, CONSTANTS, $routeParams, $location) {

        $scope.indexAction = function() {
                    MainService.query({format: 'json'}, function(data){
                        $scope.data = data;
            **This data still there when viewAction get call.**
                    });
        }

                $scope.newAction = function($event) {
                    $scope.isNew = true;
                    angular.isDefined($event)? $event.preventDefault() : false;
                    if(angular.isDefined($event)) {
                        var postData = $('#form').serialize();
                        MainService.save({format: 'json'}, postData, function(data, responseHeader){
                            var loc = responseHeader('location');
                            var r = /\d+/;
                            var dataId = loc.match(r);
                            $scope.viewAction(dataId[0]);
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        $location.path('new');
                    }
                }

                $scope.viewAction = function(ObjOrId) {
                    var dataId = null;
                    if(angular.isObject(ObjOrId)) {
                        dataId = ObjOrId.id;
                        $scope.data = ObjOrId;
                        $location.path('view/'+dataId);
                    }
                    else {
                        dataId = ObjOrId;
                        MainService.get({Id: ObjOrId, format: 'json'}, function(data) {
                            $scope.data = data;
                            $location.path('view/'+dataId);
                        });
                    }
                }


                $scope.$on('ngRepeatFinished', function(ngRepeatFinishedEvent) {

                });


        }
    ]);

    app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
        function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
                when('/new', {
                    templateUrl: 'abc.html',
                    controller: 'MainController'
                }).
                when('/view/:Id', {
                    templateUrl: 'xyz.html',
                    controller: 'MainController'
                }).
                otherwise({
                    templateUrl: 'list.html'
                })
             $locationProvider.html5Mode({
                enabled: false
            });
        }
    ])
```

The data which comes in list.html with the help of **indexAction** that still exists when view route called and I am calling viewAction and loading data from ajax but that new data does not get updated in the view.

Please help!!

Comment: You're using only templateUrl as list.html in default case, but there is no controller to be initialized in your router config. Are you sure that your MainContoller's indexAction is invoked when your list.html is loaded ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I was using ng-model in form template and that was updating the $scope.data object without submitting the form itself, So i changed input directive ng-model to ng-value and while migrating to view template there i am able to get the data.

Answer (score 1):

Your location.path looks like $location.path('new') when they should look like $location.path('/new');

Your other one looks like  $location.path('view/'+dataId) when it should look like  $location.path('/view'+ dataId);

Comment: But @rethabile template get load and i can see the UI change. If my $location.path('new') supposed to be $location.path('/new') then in the earlier case, template should not load at all? Please corrent me if i am wrong. (Sorry for delay in comment)

Comment: Can you please answer